# Calculate Mode() in Athena using group by

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, statistics, amazon-athena

I have a table 'A' with schema

```
subject, marks
```

Assume it has the following entries

```
(maths,90),(maths,90),(maths,80),(english,30),(english,30),(english,10)
```

I wish to calculate Mode() over the 'marks' column such that

```
(maths,90),(english,30) is the output
```

Can't find a way on the internet for the same for AWS Athena.
Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want:

```sql
WITH ModeRankCTE AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        subject, 
        marks,
        COUNT(*) AS marksFrequency,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ranking
    FROM A 
    GROUP BY subject, marks 
) 
SELECT 
    subject, 
    MIN(marks) AS highestMark, 
    marksFrequency, 
    ranking
FROM ModeRankCTE
WHERE ranking = 1
GROUP BY subject, marksFrequency, ranking
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a more concise way to achieve using the build-in *histogram* function:

```
SELECT subject, 
map_keys(histogram(marks))[
  array_position(
    map_values(histogram(marks)),
    array_max(map_values(histogram(marks)))
  )] as mode
FROM (
    VALUES
  ('maths',90),
  ('maths',80),
  ('maths',80),
  ('english',30),
  ('english',30),
  ('english',10)
) AS t(subject, marks)
GROUP BY subject;
```

explanation:

- *histogram(marks)* returns maps such as `{10=1, 30=2}` for 'english'
- *map_values* returns the array of the values `[1,2]`
- *array_max* returns the max values of the array `2`
- *array_position* returns the location of that max value (`2`, second element)
- *map_keys* returns the array of the keys `[10,30]`
- and finally *[ ]* returns the element in the above position (`30`, the second element)